# Performance issue in sending binary data over WebSocket

Tags: websocket

I am building a real time app which supports send file through WebSocket . My code is working fine , but it's very slow to send data to server . I am using localhost to test and it should be very fast in this case .
Why websocket is so slow ? Am I doing something wrong ? A 800kb picture takes about 2 minutes to finish . Below is my code

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/picture.jpg");
byte buffer[] = new byte[100 * 1024];
while(IOUtils.read(stream, buffer) > 0){
     session.getRemote().sendBytes(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer));
}
```

I am using **jetty WebSocket client**.

Answer (score 0):

[The WebSocket Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) itself is not slow and does not have any reason to take 2 minutes to send an 800kb picture. I suggest you to try other WebSocket client libraries and compare their performance. **[nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client)** is an example ([Blog](http://darutk-oboegaki.blogspot.jp/2015/05/websocket-client-library-java-se-15.html)). Other examples are [Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net/), [TooTallNate](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket), [android-websockets](https://github.com/codebutler/android-websockets), [jWebSocket](http://jwebsocket.org/), [Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/), [AndroidSync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync), etc.